# Java Redisson CPU utilization 90%

Tags: java, spring, caching, redisson

I'm setting up a Redis cache layer using **AWS Elasticache Redis** version **7.0.7** over **spring** framework

I'm usign Java Redisson client version **3.16.0** and java version **1.8**

Below is my Redisson client configurations

```
final Config redissonConfig = new Config();
redissonConfig.setNettyThreads(256);
redissonConfig.setThreads(128);
redissonConfig.useClusterServers()
        .setKeepAlive(true)
        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
        .setRetryAttempts(1)
        .setRetryInterval(50)
        .setPingConnectionInterval(10000)
        .setDnsMonitoringInterval(20000)
        .addNodeAddress(redisAddress);
RedissonClient client = Redisson.create(redissonConfig);
return client;
```

I'm caching the method using **@cacheable** annotation

However after deploying this change I can see the **CPU utilization reached to 90%** with increase 60%.

taking into consideration that I have set number of **NettyThreads** to **256**  and **Threads** to **128** .

Any recommendation to solve the high CPU utilization

Thanks

Comment: capture several threadumps or profile the application then analyze what is using CPU.

Comment: Did you try with the default number of nettyThreads and threads ? And yes, follow @aled advice.

Comment: Thank you @SebPerp and @ aled for your feedback, does large number of  nettyThreads and threads impact CPU utilization , I'm using AWS EC2 with type **m6g.2xlarge**

Comment: Too many things impact CPU usage. Impossible to say without captured information from the execution. Just looking at a single configuration value doesn't provide enough information.